# $f(n) = n^2 \lceil \log n \rceil$ is time constructible

Tags: logarithms, computational-complexity, information-theory

I have a question, I want to show, that:

$$f(n) = n^2 \lceil \log n \rceil $$

is time-constructible. I have no idea how to do this. I know that $n^2$ is time-constructible and I know that $\log n$ isn't. But I don't know how to prove the statement above. Any suggestions or helpful links?

Thank you!